# CMSensorRecorder - Reading historical data returns nil sometimes

Tags: swift, accelerometer

Trying to come up with a list of reasons why the CMSensorRecorder would return a Nil list when calling accelerometerData(from: to:)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmsensorrecorder/1615937-accelerometerdata

1)  We have noticed if the Watch is on the charger, this call will return Nil for that period of time.

2)  I am speculating if the Watch is in low power mode ( < 10% battery ), it could also return Nil.

3)  At times, the accelerometer does not return data in background mode. If I query the accelerometer for the same date/time range in foreground mode, I do receive data.

What are other scenarios where this situation could occur?

I am asking as our program periodically is receiving a Nil list when calling that method when the phone is not on the charger or in low power mode.

Thanks